# Angular2 with Webpack: Cannot find module 'getstream'

Tags: typescript, angular, npm, webpack, getstream-io

I have a really weird problem when building my angular2 solution with webpack (version 1.13.1).

When running the server I get an error saying:

```
Cannot find module 'getstream'
```

which is a module that I am using. The weird thing is that the module is working the way it should, and it is not required in any other place. The way I am requiring it is:

```
import stream = require('getstream');
```

Further more if I uninstall getstream using npm I get an other error, saying:

```
ERROR in ./src/main.ts
Module build failed: Error: Cannot resolve module 'getstream' in /Users/valdemarrolfsen/Utvikling/Applikasjoner/moj-web/src/lib/services
    Required in /Users/valdemarrolfsen/Utvikling/Applikasjoner/moj-web/src/lib/services/noteficationService.ts
    at ResolutionError.Error (native)
    at new ResolutionError (/Users/valdemarrolfsen/Utvikling/Applikasjoner/moj-web/node_modules/awesome-typescript-loader/dist.babel/deps.js:592:88)
    at /Users/valdemarrolfsen/Utvikling/Applikasjoner/moj-web/node_modules/awesome-typescript-loader/dist.babel/deps.js:400:37
    at run (/Users/valdemarrolfsen/Utvikling/Applikasjoner/moj-web/node_modules/core-js/modules/es6.promise.js:89:22)
    at /Users/valdemarrolfsen/Utvikling/Applikasjoner/moj-web/node_modules/core-js/modules/es6.promise.js:102:28
    at flush (/Users/valdemarrolfsen/Utvikling/Applikasjoner/moj-web/node_modules/core-js/modules/_microtask.js:18:9)
    at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:420:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:349:13)
 @ multi main
```

So the module is obviously found somehow. The module is also included in the package.json file of the project under devDependencies.

The reason why I need to fix this is that webpack allows me to run the application using:

```
npm run server
```

But if I try to build it using:

```
npm run build:prod
```

It crashes due to this error..

Comment: have you tried removing the ``node_modules`` folder and rerunning ``npm install``. Did you just misquote the way you import the getstream library or is the ``import`` statement used in that way something specific to angular? What happens when you try to require the getstream library from a node process in the same folder?

Comment: did you manage to solve this issue?

Comment: After upgrading to angular rc4, and using the angular2-webpack-starter from AngularClass, the issue solved itself!

Comment: All I did was to install get stream using

npm install getstream

And then importing it as shown above